# How to deal with two load balancer in next and prod environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have two aws ecs clusters: prod and next.

In each cluster I have one ALB and two ec2 machine with containers. the prod is running a prod app, and next is running the next app (before the prod).

```
www.example.com
next.example.com
```

Because I need to match my public dns (using nameservers from route53) to **meet only one LB**. How I deal with two load balancer? maybe a role: next.example.com to lb belong to the next-cluster? but how I do that?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean in this sentence: "Because I need to match my public dns (using nameservers from route53) to meet only one LB". The question as written doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

1) create two target groups each target group has its own ec2 instances

2) in the load balancer configuration edit rewrite rules.

3) create additional rewrite rule based on host:  next domain will forward to the next target group.

4) modify the default rule to forward to the production target group

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Answer (score 0):

Each ALB has a unique public DNS name. Use an ALIAS or CNAME record in the given zone to create a unique host name for each ALB.

In example.com:

```
www IN CNAME el my-prodelb.amazonaws.com
next IN CNAME el my-nextelb.amazonaws.com
```